# How to get rid of 'value error expected 2d array got 1d array instead' in spyder while using simple linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new to machine learning and I'm trying out simple linear regression for the first time on my pc. I am getting an error saying value error expected 2d array but got 1d array instead.

I have no clue on what to do. Any tips in fixing this code will be helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
#preparing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("Salary_Data.csv")
X = dataset.iloc[:,0].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,1].values
#Missing values
#Encoding
#splitting Dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)
#Format Scaling

#Simple Linear regressing
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

The error I got is:

```
regressor.fit(X_train,Y_train)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-4d17c24ccad2>", line 1, in <module>
    regressor.fit(X_train,Y_train)

  File "C:\Users\home\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 458, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)

  File "C:\Users\home\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 756, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator)

  File "C:\Users\home\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 552, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 2.9  5.1  3.2  4.5  8.2  6.8  1.3 10.5  3.   2.2  5.9  6.   3.7  3.2
  9.   2.   1.1  7.1  4.9  4. ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) `LinearRegression::fit()` expects that the shape of `X` is `(n_samples, n_features)` and the shape of `Y` is `(n_samples, n_targets)`. In the case in question I believe this would correspond to `(20L, 1)` and `(20L, )` (i.e. one 'row vector' of length 20 and one 'column' vector of length 20). The call

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,0].values
```

Produces an object shaped `(20L, )`. So this needs to be reshaped to `(20L, 1)` which is fairly trivial (and actually what the somewhat cryptic suggestion "use `array.reshape(-1, 1)`" is trying to tell you),

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,0].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

as @Dan has noted, an appropriate alternative is

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,[0]].values
```

Both options will produce an object of shape `(20L, 1)` which is then compatible with the `Y` object of shape `(20L, )`. Note that the shapes of `X_train` and `Y_train` shadow those of `X` and `Y`, respectively.

Comment: You can also just do this: `X = dataset.iloc[:,[0]].values` to get that correct shape